# chaining lists from class attributes

Tags: python, list, attributes, chaining

I have three classes

```
class Animals:
    def __init__(self):
         self.dog = []
         self.cat = [] 

class Dog:
    def __init__(self,age,teeth):
        self.age   = age
        self.teeth = teeth

class Cat:
    def __init__(self,age,legs):
        self.age  = age
        self.legs = legs
```

and the function:

```
def get_animals_from_attribute_value(animals_class, attribute, value):
    from itertools import chain
    animals = []
    for animal in chain( -> all attributes of animals_class, e.g. dog and cat <- ):
        x = getattr(animal, attribute, None)
        if x == value:
            animals.append(animal)
    return animals
```

The script

```
animals = Animals()

animals.dog.append(Dog(1, 2))
animals.dog.append(Dog(3, 1))
animals.cat.append(Cat(1, 3))

certain_animals = get_animals_from_attribute_value(animals,"age",1)
```

should give a list with all class instances, where the attribute age == 1. My problem right now is how to create an iterable list from all attributes of the animals-class (see 4th line in the function script).

Thank you :)

Comment: Why not implement a method on ``Animals`` that does this? There could veritably be more attributes that you *don't* to iterate over -- even if it's just automatic ones such as ``__name__``.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a reason to define `Animals` as a class. Something like `animals = dict(dogs=[], cats=[])` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__dict__` attribute, for example, to get dum1 and dum2 you can call

```
outer_class.__dict__.keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going to handle the problem now a little different:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,age,teeth):
        self.age   = age
        self.teeth = teeth

class Cat:
    def __init__(self,age,legs):
        self.age  = age
        self.legs = legs

def get_objects_from_attribute_value(input_list, attribute, value):
    output_list = []
    for object in input_list:
        If getattr(object, attribute, None) == value:
            output_list.append(object)
    return output_list
```

with

```
animals = []

animals.append(Dog(1, 2))
animals.append(Dog(3, 1))
animals.append(Cat(1, 3))

output_list = get_objects_from_attribute_value(animals, "age", 1)
```

I obtain the results, I wanted.

Ty everybody :)